# Lost conection local-remote

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I'm pretty new to programming and version-control. Working on my course task, I hit a problem with GitLab repository.

Cant resolve it over 2h with searching... and may be I'v messed up things trying different "decision"

My laptop was  accidentally restarted during merging in VS Code. When I turned it on,  somehow lost the connection between my local and remote repository.
Tried with VS and VS Code, but VS Code shows me

> "The folder currently open dosent have a git repository" .

VS shows "Add to Source Control" instead of my working branch in  bottom left corner.

In `Team explorer / Manage Connection`  in  `Local Git repositories`  this repository missing.

I've tried to add it in  `Manage Connection` this is the error message

> "No new repositories were found. Errors were encountered while searching for repositories. See the Output window for details."

I can clone it again in different folder and handle copy changed files but its  contain my over 20 hour work so I'm looking for something smarter.

Answer (score 0):

At first, move to your main project folder. There shloud be hidden folder: .git. It's a you Git database. Check is this folder is here (.git folder can be in diffrent place ),if you find it - your repository has not been deleted.

In the same folder where you find .gir folder ,try run command line (the best will be run git bash, you can run in when you click shift and PPM -> Git bash here ).

[image: Location .git folder and Git bash here command]

1. It's your hidden git database/git repository
2. Git bash here command

Next step -  run command: Git status, propably you will be have unmerged paths like this:
[image: Gir merge results Example]

If so, try run at the same main folder VS Code, check or you see your repository on VS Code.

If you will have some diffrence from git output (like corrupt repository, but it's rarity), we can tell you more. Now it's difficul say somethink more withous information from console.

Summary:

1. Check or you still have .git folder (There should be in your main project folder, but it can be in diffrent place)
2. Run git bash and check status by commend: Git Status. Check what git output. If it's neccesary - Send output results
3. After step 2 - try running VS Code in the main folder
4. Check or the VS Code you see your repository If you will have still any problems send more screen from folders and console output

Comment: git status returned -
>fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Well, if you can't find .git catalog it will be difficult to do something. It's looks like you lose your git database (from something reason. Maybe .git folder is in other place?)